# Безопасность запроса

Tags: php, pdo, select

Можно ли назвать эти два варианта кода безопасными?

*Вариант 1*

```
$name    = $_GET['name']
$go_sort = 'AND user=:name';
$count   = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE vid=1 $go_sort");

$count->execute([':name' => $name]);
```

*Вариант 2*

```
if ($_GET['name'] == 'ivan') {
    $name = 'AND user=ivan';
}
$count = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE vid=1 $name");
```

Можно ли быть уверенным, что **SQL инъекции** не грозят при таких запросах?
Если нет, то просьба указать почему.

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ!:

Вариант запроса 3

Этот запрос тоже будет безопасным?

$var = (int)$_GET['id'];

$count = $db->query("SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE vid=1 AND user_id=$var");

Переменная $var получает значение из GET, но пройти могут только цифры. Значит ли это, что запрос варианта 3 тоже безопасен и без prepare->execute?

И вариант запроса 4 тоже можно назвать безопасным?

$count = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tovar WHERE vid=1 AND user_id=:user_id");

$count->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id);

$count->execute();

На синтаксис прошу внимания не обращать. Могут быть не точности.

Comment: да, это безопасно. до тех пор пока полученные от пользователя данные непосредственно не подставляются в текст все Ok

Comment: И конструкция  $name= $_GET['name']      $count->execute([':name' => $name]);      Так же безопасна и не пропустит инъекцию?

Comment: конечно. на уровне драйвера БД подстановка имени переменной происходит во время компиляции запроса, а параметры передаются отдельно как данные и в тексте запроса не участвуют

Comment: Всё так, если не считать, что Вариант 2 сломан в `user=ivan`. У Вас же нет колонки ivan?

Comment: Если Вы про правильность синтаксиса, то конечно, мог ошибиться. Эти коды не из рабочей версии, а придуманы для примера, что бы понять в каком направлении писать безопасные запросы к БД.

Comment: Лучше в направлении варианта 1. Они не только безопасны, но и удобны при формировании, и в добавок на некоторых СУБД выполняются быстрее (за счет кеширования планов выполнения запросов, которое невозможно если внешний вид запроса отличается хоть на 1 символ)

Comment: Да, я так и планирую строить запросы через prepare->execute. Второй вариант чисто для понимания, что даже не подготовленный запрос безопасен, если не "подставляется" сам под инъекцию.

Comment: Mike  и  vp_arth  на вас одна надежда) Я там вариант 3 еще добавил. Посмотрите плз. Будет ли третий вариант тоже безопасным?

Comment: Механизмы такие, как использование принудительного приведения типов (например, с помощью функции intval()) не являются абсолютно безопасными. Существуют варианты для их обхода и к их использованию необходимо подходить с максимальным вниманием.  Я так понимаю это мой ответ на свой же вопрос по третьему варианту?